# what CSS/problem is causing this difference

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome and when I open the CakePHP documentation, this is how it shows on the `Google Chrome` :

[image: Font shown on Google Chrome]

and when I open the same page with `Firefox`, it shows better, at least more readable as shown below:

[image: Font shown on Firefox]

The page I am vising is: http://book.cakephp.org/view/898/A-Typical-CakePHP-Request

I think my font settings on Google Chrome messed up somehow and by the way I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

**EDIT:**

What I've figured out is it uses `HelveticaNeue-Light, HelveticaNeue` fonts and I need to remove it I believe.

Comment: I see it exactly the same on my Chrome. To prevent this question from being closed, you should reword it from *why is this happening on my computer* to *what CSS/problem is causing this difference*?

Comment: kind ok basic but did you try ctrl+0?

Comment: I don't know why they want to close this question. This is a major problem and relevant to a programmer.

Comment: @Braveyard: It's not about the question itself, but about the title. :)